# doesn't open the required activity due to the change of item's position after change in listview android

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have a listview with a option to open a new activity by clicking the items on the listview and I have also a search option. The problem I am facing is to open a specific activity when an item is search and found. The position number automatically changes to 0 and the item I searched and found opens the activity of the position 0's activity instead of its own activity.I understand the problem but can't solve it. Need help!

```
  package dev.edmt.advancedsearchbar;

  import android.content.Intent; 
  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  MaterialSearchView searchView;
  ListView lstView;
  final String[] values =
        {"Android ListView Item 1",
                "Android ListView Item 2",
        "Simple List View In Android",
                "List View onClick Event",
                "Android List View OnItemClickListener",
        "Open New Activity When ListView item Clicked",
                "List View onClick Source Code",
                "List View Array Adapter Item Click",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Material Search");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchView = (MaterialSearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {

            //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
            lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstView);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            if(newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()){
                List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(String item:values){
                    if(item.toString().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toString().toLowerCase()))
                        lstFound.add(item);
                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lstFound);
                lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else{
                //if search text is null
                //return default
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
                lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            return true;
        }

    });

    lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Product.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (id == 5) {
                Intent myIntent5 = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent5, 0);
            }

            if (position == 6) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 7) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), test.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView.setMenuItem(item);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change below code:

```
if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Product.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
            }
```

with following code:

```
    String text = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
    if(text.equals("String_text_of_1st_position")) {
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Product.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);

}
```